# Can't run PyCharm interpreter as root

Tags: python, kubernetes, pycharm, interpreter

I am trying to use [Kubernetes python SDK](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python#example).
I tried to run the following code:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
```

It failed with lots of errors.
When I run the same code with python from a shell, the same issue.
When I run the same code with `sudo python` from shell, it works.

I am trying to run PyCharm interperte as root.
Following the [instruction](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206587695-How-to-run-debug-programs-with-super-user-privileges) from JetBrains, I created a script shell with the name `pythonCustomInt.sh` that contains:

```
sudo python
```

I went to PyCharm settings > Project Interpreter and changed the `Base interpreter` to `/<path>/pythonCutomInt.sh` but it writes an error:

> Environment location directory is not empty

[image]
I am not sure where I need to put the script.
Any idea?

Comment: I recommend fixing the core problem.
Maybe you have already ran the client as `root` and it left some cache/config files that cannot be read when you run it as a regular user. `ls -la` to help.
Maybe sockets are blocked for your non-root user on your system (that's less likely).
If these ideas don't help, make a shell script that runs `sudo python myscript` and run it with BashSupport plugin. You won't be able to attach a debugger, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran `sudo -s` and then from the pycharm folder (`pycharm-community-2018.1.4/bin`) I ran `sh ./pycharm.sh` and it worked.